# optional autetification for socket.io

Tags: socket.io, jwt

I use socket.io-jwt library, with a code like:

```
socketio.use(require('socketio-jwt').authorize({
  secret: config.secrets.session,
  handshake: true
}));
```

But this restricts unauthenticated. I need authentication is optional, and has way to check after if you is logged or not.

There is some library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by passing fail option to the authorize function. You should call `accept(null)` in order to claim that there was no error.

```
socketio.use(require('socketio-jwt').authorize({
    secret: config.secrets.session,
    handshake: true,
    fail: function (error, data, accept) {
      if (data.request) {
        accept(null);
      } else {
        accept(null, false);
      }
    }
  }));
```